# Jersey can't add parameter when post submit

Tags: java, api, rest, jersey

I'm using Jersey 2.4.1

I dont know. Why i can't add parameter when post submit.

Parameter information should print at line number 5 in my think.

my sample code is below

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    client.register(new LoggingFilter());
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://stackoverflow.com/");

    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("x", "foo");
    form.param("y", "bar");

    target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
        .post(Entity.form(form));
}
```

result logging is..

```
1 * LoggingFilter - Request received on thread main
1 > POST http://stackoverflow.com/
1 > Accept: application/json
1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

2 * LoggingFilter - Response received on thread main
2 < 200
2 < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2 < Date: Mon, 02 Dec 2013 14:13:35 GMT
2 < Vary: *
2 < Content-Length: 195990
2 < Expires: Mon, 02 Dec 2013 14:14:35 GMT
2 < Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Dec 2013 14:13:35 GMT
2 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
2 < Pragma: no-cache
2 < Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
```

Comment: What kind of parameters do you have in mind? If form params then don't worry - LoggingFilter, by default, doesn't print out entity (try using other constructors to achieve that) but your (form)params are still sent to the server.

Comment: As i know it's true that method type is GET. but when i was using jersey 1.17. form params were printed at console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print form parameters to console log you need to instantiate `LoggingFilter` using other constructor than the default one, see [LoggingFilter(java.util.logging.Logger, boolean)](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html#LoggingFilter%28java.util.logging.Logger,%20boolean%29):

```
client.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
```

This behavior might be different from the one present in Jersey 1.x.

Comment: You are right. I resolved this problem. thanks to your response.

Comment: No problem. Can you mark this answer as accepted so other users see that it resolved your issue? Thanks.